# controller com mesmo nome (home) em areas diferente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou com problema de ambiguidade, ao ter controllers, com o mesmo nome como, HomeController em duas áreas: Admin e Backoffice é me apresentando o problema de ambiguidade, já busquei bastante assunto na NET mas nada fala sobre o assunto, além de estar utilizando Asp.net Core e MVC5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
switch (token.Perfil)
{
    case 1:
        redirection = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Paciente" });
        break;
    case 2:
        redirection = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Medico" });
        break;
    case 3:
        redirection = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Farmacia" });
        break;
    case 4:
        redirection = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Laboratorio" });
        break;

    default:
        redirection = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Medico" });
        break;
}
```

Minhas rotas:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "areas",
                  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
               );

                //routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                //routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

Comment: Qual problema está ocorrendo? poste ae mais detalhes....

Comment: Você deve está com conflito na tabela de mapeamento de rotas. Publique o conteúdo do método `RegisterRoutes` do `HttpApplication`.

Comment: Estou utilizando asp.net core não possui o RegistrarRoutes e HttpApplication

Comment: ele possui o Routes na startup junto o AddMVC... porém não tem o namespace para especificar onde ele deve buscar a homeController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para não ter problema de ambiguidade, você precisa marcar obrigatóriamente a área no controller usando o anotação "**Area**":

```
[Area("Paciente")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/Areas/Paciente/Views/Paciente/Index.cshtml");
    }
}


[Area("Medico")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/Areas/Medico/Views/Medico/Index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Pode testar minha aplicação de exemplo clicando em Login -> Redirect2

https://github.com/superrfm/aspnetcore_areas

Comment: É Isto mesmo, infelizmente acho isso erradíssimo, pois se já está dentro de uma área você ainda tem que citar que a controller está dentro da área? Além de ser ultra redundante, obrigado pela ajuda Rafael

Comment: Você acha isso pq a estrutura de pastas e suas rotas são idênticas, porém isso não precisa ser assim, então na verdade você não definiu em nenhum lugar a área. Veja o exemplo: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}" - action faz o match pelo nome do método, controller - faz o match pelo nome do controller e por fim, a area faz o match pelo atributo. Se quiser você pode criar controllers bases na pastas e só lá colocar o atributo e os outros controllers herdarem dele.